# Kendo UI input-group-addon

Tags: bootstrap-4, kendo-ui

How can I correctly use *input-group-addon* with kendo UI bootstrap-4. This's the html:

```
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="amount">Amount</label>
           <div class="input-group">
               <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
               <input id="numeric" class="form-control" type="number"
                 value="17" min="0" max="100" step="1" />
           </div>
   </div>
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aren't the [Bootstrap class names](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/input-group/) a bit off?

This should work:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
    </div>
    <input id="currency" type="number" title="currency" value="17" min="0" max="100" step="1"/>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#currency").kendoNumericTextBox({
      decimals: 2
    });
  });
</script>
```

[Example](https://dojo.telerik.com/UsIKawEv)

Also keep in mind that starting from R3 of 2021 the Kendo Bootstrap theme is based on Bootstrap v5, so if you use a newer version that might be the reason for the issue.